# Problems creating plot with boxcox using rapache module function

Tags: r, rapache

I'm trying to create a plot using boxcox function from package MASS.

but it's creating an rapache  error.

The r code:

```
<%
  csvDF<- read.csv(GET$name1, header=TRUE)
  a<-lm(csvDF[,GET$col_variable]~1)
  require(MASS)

  filename1 <- paste(tempfile(tmpdir='/var/www/images'), '.png', sep='')
  png(filename1)
  bx<-boxcox(a)
  dev.off() 
%>
```

**GET$name1 is the csv data file address.
**GET$col_variable is the variables column.

When I lose the "bx<-boxcox(a)" line the error disappear, so I guess that the boxcox causes the error.

Here are the rapache errors:

```
RApache Warning/Error!!!

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'csvDF' not found
RApache Warning/Error!!!

In addition:
RApache Warning/Error!!!

Warning messages:
RApache Warning/Error!!!

1: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step5_box_cox.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

2: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step5_box_cox.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

3: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step5_box_cox.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

4: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step5_box_cox.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

5: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step5_box_cox.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

Function brew returned an object of 'try-error'. Returning HTTP response code 500.
```

I will be gratefull for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to give a complete answer because your whole setup isn't available.  The error message (as opposed to the warnings; worry about them later) is the variable `csvDF` isn't found.  It is unclear whether this error happens before or after you call `read.csv`.  Either way, the problem isn't the call to `boxcox`.

Also note that `lm` has a data argument that could make your code clearer.  Try something like

```
lm_formula <- as.formula(paste(col_variable, "1", sep = "~"))
a <- lm(lm_formula, data = csvDF)
```

You would also benefit from separating out code that reads data, calculates statistics, creates plots and writes plots to file.